# Replace a string in a specific index in a line using python

Tags: python, replace

I'm working on a python project and I want to replace a specific word in a line in a file (text.txt) with another string. Like I have this line `<string name="AppName">old string</string>` And I want to replace the old string by a variable. That's why I don't want to use `replace('old string','new string')` I want to replace it depending on an index. Any help is highly appreciated.
To be more clear I want to replace whatever is between the first '>' and the second '<' with the new string

Comment: I don't get why `str.replace` won't fit

Comment: Because this word will be changed every time by another string so I won't always have that word Google

Comment: Please update your question with some more examples which don't have that word Google.

Comment: Surely you would just have to change the arguments passed to str.replace()

Comment: No sir. I won't always keep the same old string. I want to change it every time.

Comment: yes the position is fixed. That's what I want. How can I do it

Comment: Maybe what you're trying to do is replace whatever is between the first '>' and the second '<'. Is that it?

Comment: Yes that my idea.

Comment: @dinarobert I have edited my original answer. Maybe that works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is will replace whatever is between the first '>' and the second '<' with the given string:

```
s = '<string name="AppName">old string</string>'

def replace(s, new):
    if (i := s.find('>')) >= 0:
        if (j := s[i:].find('<')) >= 0:
            s = s[:i+1] + new + s[j+i:]
    return s

print(replace(s, 'Google'))
```

**Output:**

```
<string name="AppName">Google</string>
```

**Note:**

This would be more typically dealt with using RE

Comment: Thank you so much. What if this line exist in another file "text.txt" how can I use this function to replace it

Comment: @dinarobert I suggest you ask another question. There's nothing in your original question that mentions any kind of file handling

Answer (score 2):

Use regex replace

```
from re import sub

string = "<string name='AppName'>Google</string>"
# anything between the >< will be converted to new_var_string
replace_string = sub(r'>\w+<', f'>{new_var_string}<', string)
```

example 1:

```
from re import sub

string = "<string name='AppName'>Google</string>"
# anything between the >< will be converted to new_var_string
new_var_string = 'youtube'
replace_string = sub(r'>\w+<', f'>{new_var_string}<', string)
print(replace_string)
```

output:

```
<string name='AppName'>youtube</string>
```

example 2:

```
from re import sub

string = "<string name='AppName'>Goo1231gl125125e</string>"
# anything between the >< will be converted to new_var_string
new_var_string = 'youtube'
replace_string = sub(r'>\w+<', f'>{new_var_string}<', string)
print(replace_string)
```

output:

```
<string name='AppName'>youtube</string>
```